# How to set fade in/out image without on click

Tags: java, android

i am working on android studio. ill first tell u what i need as output. there are 2 screens. in the first one i have placed an image. what i want is that whenever that app is launched or i open it, that image in the main screen fades in for like a few seconds then after that it automatically intents to the second screen. without any button without any on click listener. i saw some tutorials though which i managed to do it by on click listener. now i want it to automatically fade in for a few seconds and then seconds screen comes. following is the code for the main screen.

Java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private static int SPLASH_TIME = 4000; //This is 4 seconds
        private ImageView object;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            object=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.fadein);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override

                public void run() {
                    Intent mySuperIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                    startActivity(mySuperIntent);
                    finish();
                }
            }, SPLASH_TIME);
        }

    public void onFade(View view) {
        Animation FadeAnim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.view_fade);
        object.startAnimation(FadeAnim);
    }
        }
```

the xml file just contains image properties and an onclick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to do is to remove the onClick function from imgView and implement the animation code lines in onCreate function before public void run(). Let me know if it works for you

Comment: it worked thanks bro. i placed it before the new handler line. thanks a lot brother. much appreciated. ; )

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener and start next Activity on it

```
FadeAnim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
        Intent mySuperIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(mySuperIntent);
        finish();
    }
});
```